# How can I add 12 hour format in jQuery datetimepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using following source to add date and time calendar in my website : http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/. In there example they didn't provide the 12 hour format. Like : 1:00 Am, 2:00 Am 11:00 Am, 2:00 PM, 3:00 PM etc.

So that I using following code to show the 12 hour format but when I add the time it's showing me less 1 hour from my selected time. For Example : If I select 6:00 PM it's showing me 5:00 PM. How can I solved this issue ?

**My js code :**

```
$('#add_date').datetimepicker({     
    timepicker:false,
    format:'d/m/Y',
    formatDate:'Y/m/d',
    minDate:'-1970/01/02', // yesterday is minimum date
    maxDate:'+2017/12/01' // and tommorow is maximum date calendar
    });

$('#add_time').datetimepicker({
    datepicker:false,
    format:'g:i A', // edited by me
    step:60
});
```

I changed the original js file (jquery.datetimepicker.full.js) to bellow (line no 1108) :

```
// edited by me
formatTime: 'g:i A',
// original code
formatTime: 'H:i',
```

**Update :**

What I am using now :

```
$('#add_time').datetimepicker({
    datepicker:false,
    format:'H:i A',
    step:60
});
```

Comment: if possible than please provide jsfiddle.

Comment: the original js file is too big, How can I add this to jsfiddle ?

Comment: do u have CDN for that file?

Comment: Okey, I am uploading to my server

Comment: ok don't require there,there is property called "hours12" make it true

Comment: I did but still same issue.

Comment: NO, It's Working, WOW. Thanks a LOT !!

Comment: ok i m posting as answer.so others can get it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code (updated):

```
$('#add_time').datetimepicker({
    datepicker:false,
    formatTime:"h:i a",
    step:60
});
```

Complete example here: https://jsfiddle.net/rdemartis/p9ezwn0n/5/

**Update:**
Or this, if you desire the same format for output:

```
$('#add_time').datetimepicker({
    datepicker:false,
    formatTime:"h:i a",
    step:60,
    format:"h:i a"
});
```

Complete example here: https://jsfiddle.net/rdemartis/p9ezwn0n/8/

Comment: It's fine but can we add this AM and PM with time ?

Comment: did you see that it's not working as expected. It's should be only show the time not with date and It's showing be 24 hours format when I complete the select

Comment: should I change anything in original .js file ?

Comment: You are Rock @demartis :)

Comment: Thanks @shibbirahmed ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There is property called

```
"hours12"
```

make it true

Comment: one issue.. It's showing me only AM time not PM time !

Comment: if possible than can i have jsfiddle?

Comment: but jsfiddle will be better,as from webpage,i can't recognize more.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/v9vqe4v0/  i have added CDN in this jsfiddle please code in this fiddle and update.share me updated fiddle please.

Comment: I have update my html and js function but why it's not showing.

Comment: there is some issue in js file or may be version which i have added,i have taken link from https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-datetimepicker here for CDN,can u please select which version do you have for js?

Comment: @shibbirahmed:sorry buddy,right now i am going offline,will work over this issue and try my best to provide you your desired result asap.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix. The Class which draws is xdsoft_current.

Old Buggy Code: Line 1891

```
if ((options.initTime || options.defaultSelect || datetimepicker.data('changed'))
   && current_time.getHours() === parseInt(h, 10)
   && ((!isALlowTimesInit && options.step > 59) || current_time.getMinutes() === parseInt(m, 10))) {
```

Fixed by Adding +1 after current_time.getHours()

```
if ((options.initTime || options.defaultSelect || datetimepicker.data('changed'))
   && current_time.getHours() +1 === parseInt(h, 10)
   && ((!isALlowTimesInit && options.step > 59) || current_time.getMinutes() === parseInt(m, 10))) {
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
$('#lectureEndTime').datetimepicker({
      format: 'H:m a',
      datepicker: false,
 });
```

I am able to see 12 hours selection option while selecting the hours and minutes.

Answer (score 0):

We have to modify only ampm attribute

```
$("#dts_from_time").timepicker({
  timeText: 'Time',
  hourText: 'hour',
  minuteText: 'min',
  currentText: 'now',
  closeText: 'Done',
  timeOnlyTitle: 'Time slot',
  hour: true,
  ampm: true, // on true condition 12hr clock
});
```